# SNR in distance estimation?

Tags: distance, snr

I'm working on a project where I locate an object using TDOA (Time Difference of Arrival) plus RSSI with trilateration method.
The object send a message to antennas near it.

The problem is I want to add accuracy on the estimation of the distance between the object and the antennas so I'm asking if there is any way to estimate that distance using SNR.
Is there a formula between SNR and distance ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Signal strength is reliable to a point. Objects getting in the way can both reduce a signal and cause reflections (that in turn cause considerable fading of an RF signal). TDOA is affected by fading in that a possibly stronger signal that has taken a longer path can "win" and give a longer distance than the direct measurement.

Noise is even less reliable and is certainly not controllable. Generally, you can include "interferers" under the umbrella of noise so it's pretty unlikely that "noise" can improve the already tenuous relationship between distance and received RF signal level.

I think the method you are using (TDOA) is likely to give you the best results without trying to figure out noise levels.

---

EDIT - As Robherc suggests using a signpost signal is a good idea - basically it can be regarded as noise but stable noise and at a set distance so, if you can ratio actual signal against sign post signal you get a something that starts to be usable. The sign post signal has to be at the same carrier frequency and can be a pulses signal with the actual signal transmitting in-between these pulses. I think it would be beneficial to modulate each carrier with some form of baseband signal (on sign post and "actual") then demod both signals to calculate relative strength.

Comment: If I understood, you're saying that adding SNR won't increase the accuracy ?
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @heisenberg I can't be definite and cover all eventualities but, yes, I can't see SNR increasing accuracy - signal strength on its own may be useful to factor in but, as I see it, TDOA is much better than strength so maybe SS can't add much and SNR nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of noise vs accuracy for TOF applications has been extensively studied. See [here for an example](https://clas-pages.uncc.edu/glenn-boreman/files/2012/11/Burns_OE_30_1991.pdf). Be aware that the subject is not simple. Among other things, it is necessary to characterize the noise. You can't just say "SNR is so many dB". Is it Gaussian? Shot noise? Band-limited Johnson noise? 1/f noise?

Answer (score 0):

While SNR may not be very reliable, as explained in other answers, you may be able to reduce possible error in your results by using multiple band signalling to detect & counteract some multipath distortion (different wavelength signals will hit constructive/destructive interferance differently from reflections).

Also, if you wanted to add a few "signpost" signalling objects at known locations, the signals from these could be used for "real time calibration" by your receiver.

Comment: The sign post signals are a good idea - I was coming back to make this suggestion but you get the credit.